# Zing scatter chart node at border gets chopped off

Tags: zingchart

I am using zing chart in my application with scatter & Line chart, everything working fine but the only problem is the scatter chart node circle gets chopped off when it is at extreme end of the chart.

Tried increasing margin, setting offset, z-index and nothing worked for me till now, any solution is appreciated.

Regards,
Smruti

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this time of writing, the only way I can think of is to adjust your scale-x and scale-y values manually based off of the values you are inserting into the chart. Perhaps a function to preprocess the data to determine a maximum value before rendering a chart would be best. In the example below, I am creating 2 charts. One with set values but does not compensate for markers cutting off the edge, and another which has a helper function to increase the maximum y value by 10%.

**HOWEVER!** There is an unreleased attribute that will be on the next release we are scheduling within the next week or two. It exposes an attribute called *mask-tolerance* which will allow markers to bleed past the plot area. Keep an eye out for that as that is the optimum solution. --I'm on the ZingChart team; let me know if you have any further questions.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "scatter", 
  plot : {
    marker : {
      size : 10
    }
  },
 series : [
  {
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,100,67,100]
  }
 ],
 plotarea :{
   padding : "10px"
 },
 scaleY : {
   values : "0:90:10"
 }
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 200, 
 width: 300 
});


function preProcessData(){
  var myValues = [35,42,67,89,25,100,67,100];
  var maxVal = Math.max.apply(null,myValues);
  var maxScale = maxVal + Math.floor(maxVal * 0.10);
  return {
    type: "scatter", 
    plot : {
      marker : {
        size : 10
      }
    },
   series : [
    {
     values : myValues
    }
   ],
   plotarea :{
     padding : "10px"
   },
   scaleY : {
     values : "0:"+maxScale+":10"
   }
  };  
}

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart2', 
 data : preProcessData(), 
 height: 200, 
 width: 300 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
  <div id="myChart2"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```